# Where in the react-js folder do I override max-http-header-size?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, http-headers

Working on a react-app(created using create-react-app)Trying to use react media player to play an mp4(size:345kb) but I get this error " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)". The solution seems to be to specify "--max-http-header-size=32000" but I don't know where to put this. I tried adding it after "npm start --max-http-header-size=32000" but that didn't work either. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What tool did you use to create your react app? `create-react-app`, `vite`, etc.

Comment: I used create-react-app